# Is this a correct predicate logic question?

Tags: predicate-logic

> There are three robots: two good robots and one bad robot. One of the
>   good robot is rich and the other is poor. Each of the two good robots
>   only makes statements which are true and the bad robot only make
>   statements which are false. Write down a statement which will
>   guarantee that one of these robots who can make such a statement must
>   be the rich good robot. Please critically justify your answer by
>   proving that it can be only made by the rich good robot, but neither
>   the poor robot man, nor the robot man.

If that is a correct question is any of the answers below correct?

**1-**

> ∀x (((Good-Robot(x) ∧ Rich(x)) ∨ ¬(Good-Robot(x) ∧ Poor(x)) ∨ ¬(Bad-Robot(x))) → Makes-True-Statement(x))

**2-**

> ∃x ((Good-Robot(x) ∧ Rich(x)) → Makes-True-Statement(x) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Write down a statement which will
>   guarantee that one of these robots who can make such a statement must
>   be the rich good robot.

That's a little unclear, but I think they mean that it should be a statement that the rich robot ... and only the rich robot ... can make.

HINT

For the first part, you just need a natural language statement like "I am a rich robot"

Of course, that statement does not work, since both the rich good robot, as well as the bad robot could be making that statement.

So, try and find a statement that can only be made by the rich robot.